# Downloading an excel file using Spreadsheet gem in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spreadsheet

I am using the Spreadsheet gem in a rails app and want to be able to download an excel file generated by Spreadsheet.  I have the following action in my controller:

```
def download_xls
  send_data  spreadsheet_report("Test",  Prospects::INQUIRY_COLUMN_ORDER),
    :filename => "Test.xls",
    :type => "application/vnd.ms-excel"
end
```

The `spreadsheet_report` method is defined in the same controller:

```
def spreadsheet_report(excel_filename, inquiry_column_order)
  book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
  sheet1 = book.create_worksheet :name => Array1[0]
  sheet2 = book.create_worksheet :name => Array2[1]

  rownum = 0
  for column in inquiry_column_order
    sheet1.row(rownum).push column
  end

  book.write "#{excel_filename}.xls"
end
```

The "Test.xls" file downloads fine, but seems to be losing the necessary formatting, with only one worksheet being created and it having only values on the first row that stretch on and on, such as "@biff_version=1536".  I am opening it with LibreOffice Calc so I don't know if that causes some issues but I am able to generate the file just fine and open it with LibreOffice Calc outside of the send_data context.  What am I missing?

Comment: By the way, `for` loops in Ruby are frowned upon. Use [`each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-each) instead whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

Sheet 2 is being created but not shown because there isn't anything in it.

Just throw in -

```
sheet2.row(0).push 'Test Row'
```

to see if anything gets put into the second sheet.

For the rows, by looking at your code your not incrementing rownum everytime you loop through each column in inquiry_column_order.

Just add

```
rownum += 1
```

in your for loop after you push data onto the sheet. Hope that works, I just started using spreadsheet today aswell :)